# Assign subdomains to separate ports on web server

Tags: subdomain, webserver, virtualhost, local-seo

I have set up an Abyss web server as a little experiment, and I want to know if it is possible to assign subdomains to different ports on the machine the web server is running on.

I have a couple web UIs that I'd like to assign subdomains:

1. `192.168.1.1:8000` becomes `example.com/webui1/`
2. `192.168.1.1:8001` becomes `example.com/webui2/`

The webUIs are available by accessing their ports via example.com:8000.

I have tried using a reverse proxy, but it seems that this is only usable on one internal IP at a time.

What other options do I have?

Answer is good, but my current set up doesn't meet the requirements. Abyss Web Server X2 is required to use Virtual Hosts with Abyss.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to make a separate `VirtualHost` for each port, like so:

```
#assuming you have this in your config
NameVirtualHost *:8000
NameVirtualHost *:8001
NameVirtualHost *:8002
NameVirtualHost *:8003 # (...)
Listen 8000
Listen 8001
Listen 8002
Listen 8003 # (...)
```

Then each `VirtualHost` looks like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:8000>
        ServerName localhost
        DocumentRoot /path/to/www/dir/1
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:8001>
        ServerName localhost
        DocumentRoot /path/to/www/dir/2
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:8002>
        ServerName localhost
        DocumentRoot /path/to/www/dir/3
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:8003>
        ServerName localhost
        DocumentRoot /path/to/www/dir/4
</VirtualHost>
```

And for each of the `/path/to/www/dir/(1,2,3,4...)` directories, you can use PHP for example, to redirect the user:

```
<?php
header('Location: http://example.com/webui2');
?>
```

Or instead use `mod_rewrite` to do that within the Apache configuration.

But this setup is incredibly inefficient, a hassle to maintain, and not worth probably what you're intending to do.

Comment: I see, as I'm using the free Abyss X1 web server I don't think Virtual Hosts is available to me. Unless I'm missing something extremely obvious.

Comment: @MichaelFrank - Well, you would simply upgrade to the version 2, which does support VirtualHosts (http://www.aprelium.com/abyssws/articles/x2-hosts.html) or install Apache instead. With your current setup, it is impossible.

Comment: As it's a small home project I don't really want to pay for an upgrade. I have tried installing Apache, but I'm having issue getting it set up on my WHS 2011.

Comment: Okay, I have got Apache set up and running but I don't see how I can point the `DocumentRoot` to the webUI of a running program.